# Set jQuery datepicker minDate depending on input

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm trying to make a jQuery datepicker set `minDate` depending on the value of a radio button.

When I try to write a function returning a string, my JavaScript keeps crashing. Any ideas on why this is not working?

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "-35:+0",
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    minDate: function() {
        var str = "-35Y";
        if($("#inputfield").val() == "value") {
            str = "-33Y";
        }
        return str;
    }
});
```

Comment: *My javascript keeps crashing.* What error are you getting?

Comment: @Rob I get: _TypeError: date.getTime is not a function_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/FPRrr/)

This works fine.... you need to make sure that you have `inputfield` with a `value`

```
 <input type='text' id='datepicker'></div>
 <input type='text' value='value' id='inputfield'>

$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "-35:+0",
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    minDate:mdate()
});


function mdate(){
        var str = "-35Y";
        if($("#inputfield").val() == "value"){
            str = "-33Y";
        }
        return str;
}
```

- Edit:*

  `$('#inputfield').on('change',function(){
       $('#datepicker').datepicker('option', 'minDate', mdate());
  });`

Comment: Thanks! No more errors! But still _minDate_ does not change for me if the input is changed. Is _yearRange_ distrupting it?

Comment: You need to bind change event on your input and in the callback do something like this $('#datepicker').datepicker('option', 'minDate', mdate());
});

Answer (score 2):

The option [`minDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate) expects a **value**, not a **function**. A datepicker will not automagically update the value of `minDate` whenever the selection of your radio button changes.

If you want the datepicker's minimum date to change whenever the radio button selection changes, then you must explicitly program this. Something along the following lines:

```
$('[name=myradiogroup]').change(function () {
    var newMininumDate = /*insert logic here*/;
    $('#datepicker').datepicker('option', 'minDate', newMininumDate);
});
```

See http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-option

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "-35:+0",
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    minDate: $("#inputfield").val()
});
```